# Unable to sudo docker pull ubuntu from windows-ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

syed@DESKTOP-E396P7V:~$ sudo systemctl status ssh
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
syed@DESKTOP-E396P7V:~$ sudo docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
syed@DESKTOP-E396P7V:~$ sudo docker.io pull ubuntu
sudo: docker.io: command not found
syed@DESKTOP-E396P7V:~$

Comment: try `sudo docker pull ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

Your docker daemon is not running, run it by executing `sudo systemctl start docker`